# A graph spectra graph problem?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I was wondering how to relate the spectra of the Zig-Zag product of two graphs in term of the factors...someone can help me?

Comment: What is the definition of the Zig-Zag product?

Comment: @RichardStanley See the wikipedia article, or the actual article cited in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The spectral gap is analyzed in the [foundational paper](http://www.math.ias.edu/%7Eavi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/SALIL/EXPANDERS/ANNALS/RVW01.pdf) I don't know if you can say anything else.

*Omer Reingold, Salil Vadhan, and Avi Wigderson*, MR 1888797 [**Entropy waves, the zig-zag graph product, and new constant-degree expanders**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/3062153), *Ann. of Math. (2)* **155** (2002), no. 1, 157--187.